# Buddypress Filter Multiple Activities

Tags: filters, buddypress

I'm trying to exclude activity updates (ones users actually post) from a custom "ticker" I'm running. With the below code, I am only displaying activities where friendships are created. How do I add another argument to allow for another activity action to display?

```
<?php if ( bp_has_activities('action=friendship_created&max=5') ) : ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?php if ( bp_has_activities('action=new_forum_post,new_blog_comment,new_blog_post,friendship_created,joined_group,created_group,new_forum_topic') ) : ?>`

Found the solution myself :)